# How to learn Operating System in depth and implement own OS

Tags: operating-system

I am learning Operating Systems, their different perspectives like different scheduling algorithms etc. My question is: Can I make my own OS as a final year project? Please suggest some good resources (i.e video training is appreciated) that helps me understand and mainly gives me the ability to DEVELOP at least a SMALL OS.

Comment: This isn't really a good stackoverflow question.  I'd recommend examining the low level hardware components that modern computers have (specifically the real time clock and the programmable interrupt controller) and figure out how they work.  From there, assuming you have a sturdy background in C/C++, and assembly language, you may be able to write a fledgling operating system.

Answer (score 6):

Check out Andrew Tanenbaum's ["Operating Systems, Design & Implementation](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/academic/product/0,,0131429388,00%2ben-USS_01DBC.html) and [Minix](http://www.minix3.org/) as well

Comment: @cprogcr ... ick.  who put that "u" so close to the "i".  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The Dinosaur book (OS Concepts by Silberschatz) is essential.

Most people no longer develop their own operating systems from the ground up since the systems integration (BIOS, hardware, etc.) is extremely difficult.  Most people end up starting with a form of Linux or Unix.

If you are trying to learn OS concepts, I would recommend looking at OS/161 and System/161.  They are projects started at Harvard used to teach the OS class to undergraduates.  It runs a scaled down form of Unix, and contains all the basics, including threads and processes, scheduling, synchronization primitives, memory management, and file systems.

Comment: Well Thank You Kevin.
I am reading The Dinosaur book (OS Concepts by Silberschatz) and i basically have a good knowledge of C/C++/Java/ALP etc and yeah ur right most of the OS developed are from Linux kernel or Linux patches that are available to create our customized OS and i even will try out some project which u mentioned.
Thanks for the information

Answer (score 3):

[Linux System Programming: Talking Directly to the Kernel and C Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009585)

this book is for those who are going to start with OS , it tells u the functions and the programming side of OS to keep it interesting . Andrew Tanenbaum's "Operating Systems, Design & Implementation is a harder book to start with .

Comment: I haven't read the whole book, but the Amazon description says "This book is about writing software that makes the most effective use of the system you're running on", and the preface says similar things.  In other words it is about _using_ an operating system, not about _writing_ an operating system which is what the questionner asked for.

Comment: @Bryan I believe knowing to program in kernel/system level gives you a more in-depth knowledge of the underlying system, thus easing the process of learning OS Design.